# Xcode - Programmatically open annotation - MapKit

Tags: xcode, annotations, mapkit, mkannotation

I have a function which zooms half way into the annotation which has been placed on the map, and the user's location, so that both can be seen on the screen. Is there a method for the annotation which displays its 'contents' i.e. simulate pressing on it? It would be ideal for it to pop open as soon as it's zoomed in.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can select an annotation with this code:
You need to modify the objectAtIndex from 0 to whatever number to display the annotation you wish.

```
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:[[self.mapView annotations] objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't seem to find the array, it says there are no elements in it. Which is strange as the annotation is on the screen. The only thing I can think of is that it's re-drawing it sometime. I'll look into it. I'll trust your code works though, thanks again.